# Recording 16-bit WAVE audio with Node.js with node-record-lpcm16

Tags: node.js, linux, audio-recording

The system I'm using is a linux distro called Raspbian (Debian-based). I'm trying to record a .wav audio file with node-record-lpcm16. It starts recording but as soon as it starts it finishes. The end time is like 56ms. Therefore the test.wav results empty. I couldn't figure out why it does not work as there are no errors occuring. Do you have any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Let me know if you fix these issue any how. I got same error.

Comment: I'm experiencing this error too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: This seems to work for me on Windows. https://github.com/gillesdemey/node-record-lpcm16/pull/28